# Get Apache to send Content-Type text/plain for PHP

Tags: apache-http-server, php, content-type-association

How do I get apache to send Content-Type text/plain for php files?

I can accomplish this in php using

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

I tried adding this to my vhost.conf (I am using Plesk) and reloading and restarting apache

```
<Directory />
    AddType text/plain php
</Directory>
```

It does not seem to help.

I also tried setting the AddType in .htaccess, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your AddType is probably overriden somewhere else in your config. Use [ForceType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype) instead.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```